# Easy way to relaunch OS X application

Tags: macos

Is there a way to add Relaunch command to application popup in Dock?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but here are some shortcuts.

For the Finder, you can actually option-right-click (or option-control-click) on the icon and it will display a relaunch option. For applications that don't exist in the dock normally, you can show them in the Finder with a command-click of the dock icon, and then quit normally. Showing the item in the Finder will let you easily restart it.

If necessary, you can also display a force-quit item by option-right-clicking any item that isn't the Finder.

For the absolute fewest possible clicks to relaunch, command-click the item in question, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> so that the item is selected, and before releasing command, hit <kbd>q</kbd> to send it a quit instruction. Still holding command, <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>`</kbd> back to the Finder (release <kbd>command</kbd> now), then hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) to launch the application that will be selected from your Show in Finder command issued earlier. One click—everything else is keyboard.

Comment: You can also temporarily add them to the Dock before quitting by moving them to a different position. After relaunch by Dock-clicking the application, remove it by dragging it out. The icon does not disappear in smoke, since it's running, but it's no longer permanently in the Dock.